# Stuck in my role with a manager who does not give any trainings or benefits or career growth

Tags: manager, micro-management

I am working as a Technical Program Manager in Sales Ops.Due to org restructure, I was moved to Sales Technology team. Ever since I moved into this team, my manager has become insecure and is not interested in my growth and career. I worked with this manager in a different capacity in my previous role (as a stakeholder). Our org has started a major migration project to create a new CRM system using out of the box features on the latest version. Inspite of promising me that I would be involved with this project in the near future and I should set aside sometime for this work for months, he has not involved with this new project yet. Any developer or QA who wishes to have a call with me during our scrum meetings, he advises them to add him or his favourite team member.He had one meeting discussing about my career aspirations and what role I would like to do going forward and advised me to share a plan with him. However, he has not approved any trainings as discussed in the plan and neither is supporting me with my career growth. When I brought up this in our 1-2-1 meeting, he advised me that I could have a chat with his manager. He has cherry picked some team members to work on the new project and providing them with training on the new version as well as training for new certifications. However, he advises me to continue doing support tickets with no timelines for progress or growth. I have been commended by my team and other teams I worked with for doing an excellent job to a high standard but with this role, I feel under valued and unappreciated with no real growth in my career.I cannot move to other teams due to hiring freeze and cannot look for roles outside of my company at this point. Please advise how I ride out this manager and make some real progress in my career.

Comment: Please edit your post to have some structure - nobody wants to read a big wall of text.

Comment: This seems more like rant: What is your actual question? "I ...  cannot look for roles outside of my company at this point" : that seems to be your main problem. Fix that first. You will not have a career at this place and if you want you need to to leave. Start working on that.

Answer (score 2):

> I feel under valued and unappreciated with no real growth in my career.

I am really sorry to hear that. Sounds like you're working in a "relationship" company - or at least in a "relationship" team, where a relationship (who you know and are on good terms with) is valued higher than what you do, aka your performance.

It's probably much more pervasive and common than we'd like to admit.

> Please advise how I ride out this manager and make some real progress in my career.

I can only see two paths out of this, and it'd probably be wise to pursue both simultaneously:

1. Lay low. Do not bring up your disappointment, discouragement, dissatisfaction with the management or anyone else. If you can find it in you, compliment the management and coworkers where they do a good job. (I don't mean boot-licking. Rather: praise where it's deserved and appropriate does go a long way.)
2. Make yourself marketable and a "hot item". Take classes, study, seek gigs, volunteering opportunities, projects, internships - **anything** where you can gain valuable experience and skills that will help you land your dream job. Understand that this part is nobody else's responsibility - this is all on you. I am sure you've heard this before: **Always be learning**.

P.S.:

> cannot look for roles outside of my company at this point.

Why not?

Answer (score 1):

> my manager has become insecure and is not interested in my growth and
> career

Unfortunately, that isn't their job nor their responsibility. In an ideal world, your manager and your company would take an interest in, and provide opportunity for, your career growth. Sadly, many do not.

If you can't find ways to find the growth opportunity you seek on your own, and if your manager and company aren't providing those opportunities, and you can't go elsewhere for a new job, you'll have to live with the situation.

Comment: Career growth and personal development should be and very often are a part of a managers responsibilities. How can you assert that it is not when you have not read the job description of the OPs manager?